# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly for a pascode system

Tags: python-3.5

im are creating a code for a password system tahe turns letter to numbers
what have i done wronge?

```
abc = "....abcdefg......hijklm........nop.qrst......uvwx.yzæøå"

def encode(letter):
    tall = abc.find(letter)

    return tall



pw1 = "bb"
output = ""

for num in range(28):
    output = ""
    for character in pw1:
        if character in abc:
            output = output +  encode(character)
        else:
            output = output + character


    print(secret)
    print(output)
```

the error code fom phyton3.5.2 is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artde/Desktop/Python/passord system.py", line 17, in <module>
    output = output +  encode(character)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` retruns the index of character in string so in your case function `encode` will return integer and `output` is string hence 
`output = output +  encode(character)` will give the error so replace it by `output = output +  str(encode(character))`

Comment: tanks. but how can i do that it becom 10 and not 55 (i mean to add the to numbers)